# nlme analysis growth curve

Tags: time-series, lme4-nlme

I am trying to fit a sigmoid curve (SSasymp or another) to a series of repeated measures data with the nlme function:

```
fm5 <- nlme(IncAlt ~ SSasymp(fecha, Asym, R0, lrc),
                fixed=Asym + R0 + lrc~ poblacion,
                random =Asym ~ 1|bloque/familia/id,data=data,
                start =c(Asym=83 ,R0=-9,lrc=-3),correlation = corCAR1(form=~fecha|id))
```

but I can´t fit it.

I am really want to know if there are differences between populations and what is the variance of families, blocks and id.

My data is a series of height measurements in different times in several plants(id), nested in families (familia), nested in Populations (poblacion), all of them randomly blocked (bloque). The measurements of each plant are correlated (AR1) but they are independent of other plants.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 fecha id bloque poblacion familia IncAlt
     1  1      1        PA      11    0.0
     2  1      1        PA      11    0.0
     3  1      1        PA      11    0.0
     4  1      1        PA      11    1.8
     5  1      1        PA      11    1.8
     6  1      1        PA      11    3.3
     7  1      1        PA      11    3.8
     ...
     1 16      1       TRB      11    0.0
     2 16      1       TRB      11    0.0
     3 16      1       TRB      11    0.0
     4 16      1       TRB      11    0.0
     5 16      1       TRB      11    0.5
     6 16      1       TRB      11    3.0
     7 16      1       TRB      11    8.5
     8 16      1       TRB      11   13.5
     9 16      1       TRB      11   14.5
     ...
    16 16      1       TRB      11   40.5
    17 16      1       TRB      11   43.0
    18 16      1       TRB      11   43.5
    19 16      1       TRB      11   43.5
    ...
```

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users.

Comment: I´m going though similar problems, I recomend you start with more simple models and then go up to harder ones. I´m following Pinheiro and Bates 2000, Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS. Maybe that could help. And since the SSasymp is an self-starting function, I think is better to remove the start option. And "corCAR1(form=~fecha|id)" needs a value between -1 and 1 before the "form".